# Have access to multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am developing an application that at the beginning the user can select which database to connect to. It is a Rails application which uses Active-Record for database access.  Usually, a Rails application is configured to connect to a specific database and then not change which database it is connected to.  How can an application which is using Active-Record select its database on the fly?

Comment: okay giving you an example

Comment: Use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection

Comment: @SeanHuber Is it possible to change the database only for a particular user?

Comment: Sure it is. I'm not sure what kind of app you're building that theoretically has a separate database connection for each user - I suspect it doesn't have many users.  But there's nothing stopping you from going meta and dynamically defining classes that inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` and establish new database connections on the fly.